# matlab editor can't compare right with arabic diacritics

Tags: matlab, arabic

I am working on removing some arabic diacritics from text files which every file contain one line. a sample of those files is shown below

مًعنى قول المصلى الله اكبر بلسان الظاهر الله اكبر ان يقيد ربى

after opening the file, I am searching for diacritics using those two lines of code

```
index = [...
        strfind(line, 'ً'),strfind(line, 'ٌ'),strfind(line, 'ٍ'),...
        strfind(line, 'َ'),strfind(line, 'ُ'),strfind(line, 'ِ'),...
        strfind(line, 'ْ'),strfind(line, 'آ'),strfind(line, 'ّ')...
        ];
line(index) = [];
```

executing them in the editor return an empty matrix, but when executing them in the command window it return a correct result.

PS: I am openening the text file with UTF-8 encoding

```
file = fopen(strcat(path,'/',files(i).name), 'r', 'n', 'UTF-8');
```

so can anyone know how to make matlab editor do correct comparison.
thanks in advance.

Comment: That is strange. So literally the same code executes rigth in the command line and wrong in the editor? That seems like a bug. Are you sure?

Comment: yes, Actually this action is happening with my friend also.

Comment: Are you sure this is a command window/editor problem and not something related to having or not having variables in the workspace? Unfortunately I can not try it as I dont have the required permissions in my PC to change encoding.

Comment: thank you for your help.